# HSQLDB persist in-memory database

Tags: jdbc, persistence, hsqldb, in-memory-database

I am using an in-memory `hsqldb` database with a `JDBC` driver.

Now, I am looking for a way to persist this database for reloading after application reboot. I came up with the following options:

1. Export .script file with sql command "SCRIPT < path > " [(link)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6734158/has-hsqldb-some-mechanism-to-saving-in-memory-data-to-file)
2. Log all statements to a log file.

Option 2 works, but it seems kind of ugly in my eyes. The script export for option 1 works too, but I seem to be unable to get the .script file back into an in-memory database.

I am thankful for any advice.

Comment: I'm a bit puzzled because if you know that you want to persist the database why not just change the connection URL from `mem:` to `file:` and specify the <path> where you want the database to be stored?

Comment: I am using a mem database for performance reasons.

Comment: There is no speed penalty. You can turn off logging on a file: database and issue a CHECKPOINT for SHUTDOWN when you want to persist the .script file.

Comment: @fredt This is interesting, because I am definitely experiencing different speed (for reading from the database). If I only change the `DriverManager` connection string from jdbc:hsqldb:mem:xxx to jdbc:hsqldb:file:xxx, the speed reduces. I am using memory tables. Why could this be?

Comment: Connect to the database that you exported as script file with the files_readonly=true property. See http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/dbproperties-chapt.html#dpc_db_file_mem

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Any ideas for persisting H2 Database In-Memory mode transaction?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18165462/any-ideas-for-persisting-h2-database-in-memory-mode-transaction)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first option is correct.

After you export the database with the `SCRIPT <path>` statement, you can get it into an in-memory database.

You need to connect to the scripted database with a read-only `file:` URL

For example if you export the database to `d:/dbfiles/mydb.script`, you will get the `mydb.script` file in the named directory. To connect to this database, use `file:d:/dbfiles/mydb;files_readonly=true`.

There is absolutely no speed difference between the above method and a mem: database.